# Georeferencing .hdf file in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, hdf

Using a Noggin 250 GPR and Smart Cart. I generated data for a grid. I did not have a gps unit on the smart cart. I do have gps x'y for the corners of each grid. After post processing the data in EKKOmapper. I exported out 3D data. I have two different types of data. One is a [.hdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) file.

Is it possible to georeference a .hdf file in ArcGIS?

Comment: According to ArcGis [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000), the .hdf file is a support format so I would imagine that it can be georeferenced, or possibly a world file created for it.

Comment: Do you have experience with georeferencing in ArcGIS? If not, there is information [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/) about the fundamentals and how to georeference using specific x,y coordinates (which I think is what you are after) located [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/entering_specific_x_y_coordinates/009t000000mr000000/) . Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the input. My concern is that there does not seem to be a .hdf out put on the georeferencing tool.